# Access a Grails controller variable from a common js file

Tags: javascript, grails

When a user logged in, the first page they see is the dashboard. In my `DashboardController` I have a static string. I want to get that string value and assign it to a variable in a common js file. That common javascript file is included in all view pages. How can I do that without using `<g:javascript>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Grails javascript tag. 
http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Tags/javascript.html

```
<g:javascript>

     var myVariable = "${grailsVar}";

</g:javascript>
```

If you are using the javascript variable elsewhere in your javascript, make sure that the variable is defined prior to using the variable at other places.

Comment: The problem is I need this code in my common.js file, not in a gsp page. This common.js file is included to all gsp pages.

Comment: I am not aware of any way to get that code into your common.js file. In my experience, you declare the variable as mentioned before just before the common.js file. Then you can use the variable declared here in your common.js file in any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is your controller.

```
class DashboardController () {

//Action
 def dashboard () {

      def dashboardData = "data which you access on dashboard page goes here"

     return [data :dashboardData]
  }
}
```

In your gsp page acess data variable like this:

dashboar.gsp

```
<script>

    var dashboard = ${data};

    console.log(dashboard);``

</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: The problem is I need this code in my common.js file, not in a gsp page. This common.js file is included to all gsp pages